# PL/SQL error on saving of Nested XML in table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to save XML in a table. The XML has a format like the following:

```
<employees>
  <employees_id> 1</employees_id>
  <employees_name>Teradata</employees_name>
     <department_id>100</department_id>
     <department_name>Techinical</department_name>
     <department_id>200</department_id>
     <department_name>Management</department_name>
     <department_id>300</department_id>
     <department_name>Telecom</department_name>
  </employees>
  <employees>
  <employees_id> 2</employees_id>
  <employees_name>AT&T</employees_name>
     <department_id>400</department_id>
     <department_name>Techinical</department_name>
     <department_id>500</department_id>
     <department_name>Management</department_name>
     <department_id>600</department_id>
     <department_name>Telecom</department_name>
  </employees>
```

My table has only an id column and xmltype column.

The procedure which I am using is as follows:

```sql
   DECLARE
   CTX         DBMS_XMLGEN.CTXHANDLE;
   LCLOB$XML_AS_CLOB  CLOB;
   LREC$EMPLOYEES_EMPNO NUMBER;
 BEGIN
  FOR LREC$EMPLOYEES_EMPNO IN (198, 197, 180)
   LOOP
    --Create context for XML
    CTX :=
      DBMS_XMLGEN.NEWCONTEXT (
       'SELECT employees.EMPLOYEE_ID, employees.FIRST_NAME, 
        departments.DEPARTMENT_ID, departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME
        FROM EMPLOYEES, departments
        WHERE employees.department_id = departments.department_id and 
        employees.employees_id =' || LREC$EMPLOYEES_EMPNO);
    --Get XML file of Context
     -- Set the row header to be EMPLOYEE
    DBMS_XMLGEN.setRowTag(CTX, 'EMPLOYEE');
    LCLOB$XML_AS_CLOB := DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML (CTX);
    DBMS_XMLGEN.CLOSECONTEXT (CTX); 
    INSERT INTO HR.OFFLINE_XML (id, XML_FILE)
       VALUES ( LREC$EMPLOYEES_EMPNO, XMLTYPE (LCLOB$XML_AS_CLOB));
    END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
 END;
```

Error report:

```
 ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + / at mod remainder rem .. <an exponent (**)> ||
   multiset year day
ORA-06550: line 18, column 16:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national charac
ORA-06550: line 19, column 23:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national charac
ORA-06550: line 20, column 16:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national charac
ORA-06550: line 21, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
The symbol "b
ORA-06550: line 24, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "COMMIT" when expecting one of the following:

   end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
   member constructor map
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Exception stack, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Noel said, you can't supply fixed values to a `for` loop like that. (All the other errors in your report are knock-ons from that, though there are other problems). You can supply a range, as `for i in 1..10 loop`, but that doesn't help you here, even for your sample data. As it's just for testing you can use a dummy cursor for now:

```
    FOR LREC$EMPLOYEES_EMPNO IN (
        SELECT 198 AS employee_id FROM dual
        UNION ALL SELECT 197 FROM dual 
        UNION ALL SELECT 180 FROM dual
    ) LOOP
```

(Although I actually prefer DazzaL's array, but I'll stick with this for now). You don't have to declare the cursor, and the `number` variable you declared with that name will be superseded by this version. And when you refer to one of the values it returns it has to be by name, so in this case `LREC$EMPLOYEES_EMPNO.employee_id`. Persoanlly I'd go for a shorter name *8-)

As DazzaL also mentioned you don't need the intermediate CLOB either. It also seems unnecessary to create and close the context each time around the loop, when you can use a bind variable instead.

This works and gets the same result as your version (suitable amended), but not the output you suggested you wanted in the question:

```
DECLARE
    ctx DBMS_XMLGEN.CTXHANDLE;
BEGIN
    ctx := DBMS_XMLGEN.NEWCONTEXT(
       'SELECT employees.EMPLOYEE_ID, employees.FIRST_NAME, 
        departments.DEPARTMENT_ID, departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME
        FROM EMPLOYEES, departments
        WHERE employees.department_id = departments.department_id and      
        employees.employee_id = :id');
    DBMS_XMLGEN.setRowTag(ctx, 'EMPLOYEE');
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT 198 AS employee_id FROM dual
        UNION ALL SELECT 197 FROM dual 
        UNION ALL SELECT 180 FROM dual
    ) LOOP
        DBMS_XMLGEN.SETBINDVALUE(ctx, 'ID', r.employee_id);
        INSERT INTO OFFLINE_XML (id, xml_file)
        VALUES (r.employee_id, DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE(ctx));
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_XMLGEN.CLOSECONTEXT(ctx); 
END;
/
```

Which populates the table with:

```
        ID XML_FILE
---------- --------------------------------------------------
       198 <ROWSET>
             <EMPLOYEE>
               <EMPLOYEE_ID>198</EMPLOYEE_ID>
               <FIRST_NAME>Bob</FIRST_NAME>
               <DEPARTMENT_ID>1</DEPARTMENT_ID>
               <DEPARTMENT_NAME>First</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
             </EMPLOYEE>
           </ROWSET>

       197 <ROWSET>
             <EMPLOYEE>
               <EMPLOYEE_ID>197</EMPLOYEE_ID>
               <FIRST_NAME>Adam</FIRST_NAME>
               <DEPARTMENT_ID>1</DEPARTMENT_ID>
               <DEPARTMENT_NAME>First</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
             </EMPLOYEE>
           </ROWSET>

       180 <ROWSET>
             <EMPLOYEE>
               <EMPLOYEE_ID>180</EMPLOYEE_ID>
               <FIRST_NAME>Charlie</FIRST_NAME>
               <DEPARTMENT_ID>2</DEPARTMENT_ID>
               <DEPARTMENT_NAME>Second</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
             </EMPLOYEE>
           </ROWSET>
```

Answer (score 2):

declare an array to iterate through:

```
DECLARE
   CTX         DBMS_XMLGEN.CTXHANDLE;
   LCLOB$XML_AS_CLOB  CLOB;
   type number_tab is table of number;
   t_num number_tab := number_tab(198,197,180);
 BEGIN
  FOR idx IN t_num.first..t_num.last
   LOOP
    --Create context for XML
    CTX :=
      DBMS_XMLGEN.NEWCONTEXT (
       'SELECT employees.EMPLOYEE_ID, employees.FIRST_NAME, 
        departments.DEPARTMENT_ID, departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME
        FROM EMPLOYEES, departments
        WHERE employees.department_id = departments.department_id and 
        employees.employees_id =' || t_num(idx));
    --Get XML file of Context
     -- Set the row header to be EMPLOYEE
    DBMS_XMLGEN.setRowTag(CTX, 'EMPLOYEE');
    LCLOB$XML_AS_CLOB := DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML (CTX);
    DBMS_XMLGEN.CLOSECONTEXT (CTX); 
    INSERT INTO HR.OFFLINE_XML (id, XML_FILE)
       VALUES ( t_num(idx), XMLTYPE (LCLOB$XML_AS_CLOB));
    END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
 END;
 /
```

a couple of other points. first with dbmx_xmlgen you should be using binds and not splicing in ther literal here:

```
employees.employees_id =' || LREC$EMPLOYEES_EMPNO);
```

also you can use `getxmltype` instead of `getxml` at the end, to save you getting a clob and then having to XMLTYPE() in the insert.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't write the FOR loop this way. You should write a cursor to select the employee numbers and then use the cursor in the FOR loop.

```
declare
    cursor cur_emp is select employee_id from employees;
begin
    for i in cur_emp
    loop
    /*your code here. Use i.employee_id to get the employee_id*/
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: i can't use cursor in for loop, as i am implementing a procedure which has fixed employee_id. These id will be passed to function but for here i am doing it like his.. just for testing